# Entity Framework: LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types

Tags: entity-framework, primitive-types

I wrote a method to allow for an Expression to be passed in for the orderby clause, but I ran into this problem.

> Unable to cast the type
>   'System.DateTime' to type
>   'System.IComparable'. LINQ to Entities
>   only supports casting Entity Data
>   Model primitive types.

Basically the expression is this:

```
Expression<Func<K, IComparable>> orderBy
```

And is used like this:

```
SomeEntities.SomeTable
.Where
(
   whereClause
)
.Select
(
   selectClause
)
.OrderBy(orderBy)
```

The idea is so that I can use a dictionary to hold string matches to expressions like:

```
_possibleSortForForumItem.Add("CreateDate", item => item.CreateDate);
```

Then I have a method that takes in the sort string and returns the expression if it matches a key in the dictionary, if not returns some default. (The idea being a way to control what it can be ordered by)  Now this works for String properties, but so far not for datetime or integer as I get the error message above.

Now far as I (loosely) understand the problem is that Entity Framework needs it to be a Primary/EDM type because it has to convert the C# DateTime into something the database can handle.

Is there a way to convert the datetime to a primitive type so that this will still work?

**Solution**

The method for getting the order by method: (Take in a query and return it in "ordered form")

```
private static Func<IQueryable<ForumViewItem>, IOrderedQueryable<ForumViewItem>> GetMethodForSort(String sortBy)
{
  if (_methodForSort == null)
  {
    _methodForSort = new Dictionary<String, Func<IQueryable<ForumViewItem>, IOrderedQueryable<ForumViewItem>>>();
    _methodForSort.Add(SortForumViewItemCreatedOn, item => item.OrderBy(innerItem => innerItem.CreatedOn));
    ...
  }

  Func<IQueryable<ForumViewItem>, IOrderedQueryable<ForumViewItem>> orderMethod;

  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) || !_methodForSort.ContainsKey(sortBy))
  {
    orderMethod = _methodForSort["ForumName"];
  }
  else
  {
    orderMethod = _methodForSort[sortBy];
  }

  return orderMethod;
}
```

The method signature for the generic query method:

```
IList<K> GetListForGrid<T, K>(this ObjectQuery<T> query, ... Func<IQueryable<K>, IOrderedQueryable<K>> orderBy, ...)
```

And the use of the passed in method:

```
initialQuery = query
  .Where
  (
    somethingEqualsSomething
  )
  .Select
  (
    selectClause
  );

var orderedQuery = orderBy(initialQuery);

returnValue = orderedQuery
  .Skip(numberToShow * realPage)
  .Take(numberToShow)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Entity Framework makes this difficult and I'm not sure there's a way to do what you want to do with a single return value type (IComparable, object, etc). You might consider reworking your design into a dictionary of name-to-`Func<IQueryable<K>, IOrderedQueryable<K>>` values:

```
_possibleSortForForumItem.Add("CreateDate", 
    query => query.OrderBy(item.CreateDate));
```

And then applying it like so:

```
var orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(item => item.DefaultOrderColumn);

Func<IQueryable<K>, IOrderedQueryable<K>> assignOrderBy = null;

if (_possibleSortForForumItem.TryGetValue(orderColumnName, out assignOrderBy))
{
    orderedQuery = assignOrderBy(query);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest a IOrderedQueryable<K> as result of the Func, this will force at compile time a OrderBy is used, because for instance paging does not like non ordered queries.

Comment: Took me a couple minutes to figure out how to work this, but in the end it is very workable.

Comment: Be carefull, if I'm not mistaken, this signature only applies to IEnumerables, not IQueryables. Again, if I'm not mistaken, it means that this will be run on the result set, so the LINQ engine will not translate this to SQL, but will treat it as an in-memory ordering after the query.

Comment: Oh right, this gets applied to an ObjectQuery wich overrides both signatures. My mistake.

Answer (score 25):

I know this is old, but I was looking to accomplish the exact same thing as the OP and didn't want to use the `Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>` in my dictionary. Mostly because I would have to implement both an `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` delegate.

I ended up creating an extension method for IQueryable called `ObjectSort` which will simply check to see what the return type of the expression should be and then create a new lambda using that type so that LINQ to Entities won't freak out.

I'm not sure if this is a good solution or not but the example below does work for `DateTime` and `int` so hopefully it can give you some ideas if you're looking to accomplish something similar!

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ObjectSort<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, SortOrder order = SortOrder.Ascending)
{
    var unaryExpression = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;
    if (unaryExpression != null)
    {
        var propertyExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
        var parameters = expression.Parameters;

        if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
            return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
        }

        if (propertyExpression.Type == typeof(int))
        {
            var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(propertyExpression, parameters);
            return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(newExpression) : entities.OrderByDescending(newExpression);
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException("Object type resolution not implemented for this type");
    }
    return entities.OrderBy(expression);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great extension! Still it does not sort string columns correctly. I fixed this by changing the last line to:
`return order == SortOrder.Ascending ? entities.OrderBy(expression) : entities.OrderByDescending(expression);`

Answer (score 5):

Encountered a similar problem as the original poster, where "Order By" expressions where written as lambdas of the type Expression<Func<T, object>>. These were interpreted correctly by the NHibernate linq provider, but migrating to EF 5 resulted in "Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.IComparable'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."

The following methods provide a conversion to Expression<Func<T, TKey>> when calling the various "OrderBy" methods (using reflection - apologies...) Note they were originally encapsulated in a generic class OrderBy<T>.

```
    private static readonly Type QueryableType = typeof(Queryable);

    // HACK: Use reflection to call strongly-typed methods instead of object-based methods
    // This is to work around "Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."
    private IOrderedQueryable<T> ApplyOrderByTo(
        IQueryable<T> query,
        Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector,
        bool sortAscending,
        bool useReflection)
    {
        if (useReflection)
        {
            var body = keySelector.Body as UnaryExpression;
            var keyExpr = body.Operand as MemberExpression;

            return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)query.Provider.CreateQuery(
                Expression.Call(
                QueryableType,
                sortAscending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending",
                new Type[] { typeof(T), keyExpr.Type },
                query.Expression,
                Expression.Lambda(keyExpr, keySelector.Parameters)));
        }
        else
        {
            if (sortAscending)
                return query.OrderBy(keySelector);
            else
                return query.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
        }
    }

    // HACK: Use reflection to call strongly-typed methods instead of object-based methods
    // This is to work around "Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."
    private IOrderedQueryable<T> ApplyOrderByTo(
        IOrderedQueryable<T> query,
        Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector,
        bool sortAscending,
        bool useReflection)
    {
        if (useReflection)
        {
            var body = keySelector.Body as UnaryExpression;
            var keyExpr = body.Operand as MemberExpression;

            return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)query.Provider.CreateQuery(
                Expression.Call(
                QueryableType,
                sortAscending ? "ThenBy" : "ThenByDescending",
                new Type[] { typeof(T), keyExpr.Type },
                query.Expression,
                Expression.Lambda(keyExpr, keySelector.Parameters)));
        }
        else
        {
            if (sortAscending)
                return query.ThenBy(keySelector);
            else
                return query.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I found very simple solution to your problem (and mine too). When you create your search expression, you should pass over type of property (you know it then) but store expression in dynamic variable:

```
Expression<Func<TObject, DateTime>> Expr = obj=>obj.StartDate;
dynamic dynExpr=Expr;
```

Now you can store dynExpr in a table or anywhere you want, together with int expressions, string expressions, ... and when the time is come you can use it in OrderBy method. But not in standard way (extension method):

```
query=query.OrderBy(dynExpr);
```

, only this way:

```
query=Queryable.OrderBy(query, dynExpr);
```

In this way you can use one expression in all sorting functions (OrderBy, OrderByDescending, ThenBy, ThenByDescending).

Comment: This exactly solved my problem, since I want to dynamically build search predicates and column orderings with many different data types.

Answer (score 1):

With inspiration from OldNic I created a couple of extension methods for sorting by members. It works great for me. I am also using System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder enum to define sort order.

```
        /// <summary>
    ///     Supports sorting of a given member as an expression when type is not known. It solves problem with LINQ to Entities unable to
    ///     cast different types as 'System.DateTime', 'System.DateTime?' to type 'System.Object'.
    ///     LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">entity type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="query">query to apply sorting on.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">the member expression to apply</param>
    /// <param name="sortOrder">the sort order to apply</param>
    /// <returns>Query with sorting applied as IOrderedQueryable of type T</returns>
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByMember<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query, 
        Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, 
        SortOrder sortOrder)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;

        if (body != null)
        {
            var memberExpression = body.Operand as MemberExpression;

            if (memberExpression != null)
            {
                return
                    (IOrderedQueryable<T>)
                    query.Provider.CreateQuery(
                        Expression.Call(
                            typeof(Queryable), 
                            sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending",
                            new[] { typeof(T), memberExpression.Type }, 
                            query.Expression,
                            Expression.Lambda(memberExpression, expression.Parameters)));
            }
        }

        return sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? query.OrderBy(expression) : query.OrderByDescending(expression);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Supports sorting of a given member as an expression when type is not known. It solves problem with LINQ to Entities unable to
    ///     cast different types as 'System.DateTime', 'System.DateTime?' to type 'System.Object'.
    ///     LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">entity type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="query">query to apply sorting on.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">the member expression to apply</param>
    /// <param name="sortOrder">the sort order to apply</param>
    /// <returns>Query with sorting applied as IOrderedQueryable of type T</returns>
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenByMember<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query, 
        Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, 
        SortOrder sortOrder)
    {
        return ((IOrderedQueryable<T>)query).ThenByMember(expression, sortOrder);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Supports sorting of a given member as an expression when type is not known. It solves problem with LINQ to Entities unable to
    ///     cast different types as 'System.DateTime', 'System.DateTime?' to type 'System.Object'.
    ///     LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">entity type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="query">query to apply sorting on.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">the member expression to apply</param>
    /// <param name="sortOrder">the sort order to apply</param>
    /// <returns>Query with sorting applied as IOrderedQueryable of type T</returns>
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenByMember<T>(
        this IOrderedQueryable<T> query, 
        Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, 
        SortOrder sortOrder)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;

        if (body != null)
        {
            var memberExpression = body.Operand as MemberExpression;

            if (memberExpression != null)
            {
                return
                    (IOrderedQueryable<T>)
                    query.Provider.CreateQuery(
                        Expression.Call(
                            typeof(Queryable), 
                            sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? "ThenBy" : "ThenByDescending",
                            new[] { typeof(T), memberExpression.Type }, 
                            query.Expression,
                            Expression.Lambda(memberExpression, expression.Parameters)));
            }
        }

        return sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? query.ThenBy(expression) : query.ThenByDescending(expression);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the only solution that works perfectly!